# Dining Philosophers, Java and Monitors: IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

For disclosure, this is a homework problem regarding the classic Dining Philosophers dilemma.

Right now,  gives an IllegalMonitorStateException when a Thread is told to wait() because one of the chopsticks already has a wait() monitor on it.

The Monitor class is instantiated once, with the number of philosophers as an argument. The monitor class looks like this:

```
public class Monitor 
{
        int iPhilosophers = DiningPhilosophers.DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_PHILOSOPHERS;
        // monitors for chopsticks maybe use condition??
        public final Object[] sticks = new Object[iPhilosophers];

        // Store philosopher states in monitor. 
        public enum State {THINKING, HUNGRY, EATING, TALKING};
        public volatile State[] states = new State[iPhilosophers];
        public int[] positions = new int[iPhilosophers];


    public Monitor(int piNumberOfPhilosophers)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<piNumberOfPhilosophers; i++) {
            System.out.println("Philosopher " + (i+1) + " is " + this.states[i]);
            this.sticks[i] = new Object();

        }
    }

    /**
     * Grants request (returns) to eat when both chopsticks/forks are available.
     * Else forces the philosopher to wait()
     */
    public synchronized void pickUp(final int piTID)
    {
        int posn = piTID - 1; // due to piTIDs starting at 1, but stick positions @ 0
        this.states[posn] = State.HUNGRY;
        System.out.println("Hungry Philosopher "+ piTID + " is trying to pickup sticks");

        test(posn);
        System.out.println("Philosopher " + piTID +" is state " + this.states[posn]);
        if (this.states[posn] != State.EATING)
            try {
                System.out.println("Hungry Philosopher "+ piTID + " was told to work on his table manners and wait!");
                this.sticks[posn].wait();
//              synchronized (this.sticks[posn]){
//                  this.sticks[posn].wait();
//              }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
        /**
     * Test the chopsticks on the left and right of the philosopher
     * Give philosopher's position
     */
    public void test(int i){
        System.out.println("Entered test function with posn : " + i);
        System.out.println("left "+this.states[(i+iPhilosophers-1) % iPhilosophers]);
        System.out.println("right "+this.states[(i+1) % iPhilosophers]);
        System.out.println("currently " + this.states[i]);

        // Check if philosophers on left and right are not eating
        if ( (this.states[(i+iPhilosophers-1) % iPhilosophers] != State.EATING) &&
                (this.states[(i+1) % iPhilosophers] != State.EATING) &&
                (this.states[i] == State.HUNGRY) ) {
            // set this state to eating, and signal the chopstick

            this.states[i] = State.EATING;
            System.out.println("Set position " + i + " to " + this.states[i]);
            synchronized (this.sticks[i]) {
                this.sticks[i].notifyAll();
                System.out.println(i + " posn notified all");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * When a given philosopher's done eating, they put the chopstiks/forks down
     * and let others know they are available.
     */
    public synchronized void putDown(final int piTID)
    {
            System.out.println("entered putdown");
            int posn = piTID - 1; // due to piTIDs starting at 1
            this.states[posn] = State.THINKING;
            test((posn+iPhilosophers-1) % iPhilosophers);
            test((posn+1) % iPhilosophers);
            System.out.println("Philosopher " + piTID + " is back to " + this.states[posn]);
        }
}
```

part of the output generated:

```
Philosopher 4 is state HUNGRY
Hungry Philosopher 4 was told to work on his table manners and wait!
Hungry Philosopher 2 is trying to pickup sticks
Entered test function with posn : 1
left EATING
right EATING
currently HUNGRY
Philosopher 2 is state HUNGRY
Hungry Philosopher 2 was told to work on his table manners and wait!
Exception in thread "Thread-3" Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at Monitor.pickUp(Monitor.java:61)
    at Philosopher.run(Philosopher.java:87)
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at Monitor.pickUp(Monitor.java:61)
    at Philosopher.run(Philosopher.java:87)
```

I've tried a few different things, but can't figure out how to allow any philosopher to wait() if another one is already waiting. Do I need to use conditions?

Note that this is similar to the question [Dining Philosophers monitor approach in Java: no interleaved thread execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189208/dining-philosophers-monitor-approach-in-java-no-interleaved-thread-execution) which is based on the same O/S book, but hasn't helped me resolve this problem.

Comment: Read the javadoc of `wait()`.

Comment: +1 for the nicely thought out question and background research. Asking for help is fine, as long as you're not asking us to do your homework for you (which you aren't, so, nice one).

Comment: It's not really the dining philosophers problem if you have one gigantic lock above everything though. Also the write to a volatile array is not volatile, but with all the locking going on I think that's not necessary anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have

```
        System.out.println("Hungry Philosopher "+ piTID + " was told to work on his table manners and wait!");
        this.sticks[posn].wait();
```

you need to be `synchronized` (aka own monitor) on `this.sticks[posn]` object to invoke either `wait()` and `notify` methods on that object.

Correct apporach you have later in your code

```
synchronized (this.sticks[i]) {
            this.sticks[i].notifyAll();
            System.out.println(i + " posn notified all");
        }
```

You are synchronizing yourself on `this.sticks[i]` and that calling `notifyAll()`. Do the same with `wait()` case.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. Doing that seems to have gotten rid of the IllegalStateException error, however now there is deadlock. After eating, the philosopher can't putDown() his chopsticks. I imagine this may be because another philosopher might be trying to put his own chopsticks down, although I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up changing everything to use conditions and locks. Not the best way to solve this, but the assignment states we can.